# It is possible to not increment count in for loop - Python

Tags: python

it is possible to not increment count in for loop in case an error happen, like this example

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print(i)
    except: # if and error happen in i == 5 the next iteration will be 5 not 6 
        pass
```

I want to repeat the same iteration when the error happen. And thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `range()` if you want more control over how it increments.

Comment: Since a `for loop` in python is technical a `foreach loop`, you should change your loop to a `while loop` to have more control.

Comment: It's not necessary I use ```range()``` it's just example it could be list.

Comment: I ask if there is a way in for loop

Comment: Do you need it to be executed only `10` times including erros or repeat each iteration until it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: repeat until no error throw then increment iteration

Answer (score 2):

When you use `for...in` there's no way to avoid going to the next item in the iteration when the loop repeats.

You can use a nested loop to keep trying with the same value of `i` until you don't get an error:

```
for i in range(10):
    while True:
        try:
            print(i)
            break
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wrap all into a `while` loop:

```py
for i in range(10):
    while True
        try:
            # whatever you have to do
            print(i)
            break
        except: 
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Python's `for` loop is technically a `foreach` loop you should use a `while` instead of `for` for more control.

```
i = 0
while i<10:
    try:
        #Do stuf
        i += 1
    except:
        pass
```

If an error happens before `i += 1` it will not be incremented.